# Safari not firing touch events

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

I've got a small jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/qhguktsn/5/. When you tap the text at the top of the link (iOS mobile Safari), you get only the mouse events- no touch events at all, not even on the body. If you tap it on the bottom of the text, you get touch events. We depend on touch events for handling 300ms delay.

How can we get touch events for tapping on the top of the text as well as the bottom?

HTML:

```
<div style="margin-left:200px;margin-top:200px">
    <a style="vertical-align:center;height: 20px, width: 20px;font-size:100px" href="javascript: void 0">text</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery("a").on("mousedown", function() { document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("mousedown ")); });
jQuery("a").on("mouseup", function() { document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("mouseup ")); });
jQuery("a").on("touchstart", function() { document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("touchstart ")); });
jQuery("a").on("touchend", function() { document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("touchend ")); });
jQuery("a").on("click", function() { document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("click ")); });

jQuery(document.body).on("touchstart", function() { document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("body touchstart ")); });
jQuery(document.body).on("touchend", function() { document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("body touchend ")); });
```

Comment: I think I might have the same thing on iOS 8.1.2 with Chrome.

Comment: Chrome uses the same rendering engine as Safari on iOS so the behaviour should be identical (as it should be with all other browsers running on iOS).

Comment: I have been trying hard to find out why touch events on my small button were not firing consistently and your post helped me understand that it is an edge problem! The touch events fail to fire as long as you're tapping too close to any edge, including the left and right edges, but the click events still fire.

Comment: Have the same issue with Chrome on Android.

Comment: Did a test using jQuery Mobile 'tap' event. The 'tap' event appears to trigger at the edges even if touch start does not. Not sure why. May be something to explore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The touch events on the body are due to the body element being shifted down by the margin-top, putting an outline on the body element outlines the touch-target:

```
body { outline: 1px solid red; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qhguktsn/11/

The second part of the mystery seems to be that the click target expands outside the touch-target:

[image: screenshot of text]

Touching the red outline will not trigger a touch event on the body element, but the click event seems to fire when tapped anywhere within the grey `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` region which expands outside the anchor itself. Taps at the very top will therefore trigger click events on the anchor, but not touch events on the body.

Comment: The primary issue here is that the area which is affected is way too small- in real tests there's a substantially larger band at the top that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Seems that the browser interprets the tap as always much higher than the user thinks they tapped, so between those two issues, this could be it.

Comment: @Douglas thanks for shedding some light on this mystery. Is there a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 13):

This is know bug in Mobile Safari. https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105406
There is another one as well with adding node form different document. https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=135628

In order to fix them there are several ways.

- The first one is to use a small library called [fastclick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick), which supports many mobile devices and OS.
- The second options is to add `event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault();` like that. You need both of them.

  ```
  jQuery("a").on("mousedown", function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      event.preventDefault();
      document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("mousedown ")); 
  });
  ```
- The third option is by using the viewport meta tag like that `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">`. This will eliminate all touch delays, without any workarounds. But, again on Safari it may not act like in the other browsers, because hey [Safari is the new IE](http://nolanlawson.com/2015/06/30/safari-is-the-new-ie/)

There is also [touch-action](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action), but it's not supported in most of the mobile browsers. :(

Comment: I'm not really convinced about this bug, since we're experiencing different behaviour depending on where on the button you tap. And the fixes you've listed don't really apply. Fastclick only does the same as what we've done, I'm really not sure how cancelling a mouse event will make a preceeding touch event magically appear, and the third option as you've said doesn't apply to Safari so I really don't see the relevance.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more helpful. I don't have any more ideas at the moment.

Comment: Btw, check the link at the bottom of this post. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4165641/2855530

Answer (score 2):

I found that the touch event is not fired when clicking on an element contained by a position:fixed element that extends beyond the window. I handled this by making the parent container shorter (used JS to get the exact window height).

This problem was in an app UIWebview using iOS 10. (Yes, still using UIWebview)